# Haskell-Use instance function for pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a simple expression tree with plus and minus operations.

I implemented a class "Group" with the following function signatures:

```
-- type class  Group a ---------------------------------------------------------

class (Eq a, Show a, Read a, Num a) => Group a where 
add :: a -> a -> a
identity :: a 
invers :: a -> a
```

Add gets two elements and returns the sum (e.g. 4+7 = 11), identity is a special element that leaves other elements unchanged (i.e. 0 because 3 + 0 = 3) and invers calculates the inverse of a element (e.g. inverse of 3 is -3).

The instance of this class is for values of type integer, therefore it looks like this:

```
-- Group Integer  ----------------------------------------------------------------

instance Group Integer where 
  add x y = x+y
  invers x = -x
  identity = 0
```

The expression tree should consist of the following data elements:

```
-- expression tree with values having Group property ---------------------------

 data  Expr a = Lit a | Invers (Expr a) | Add (Expr a) (Expr a) deriving (Eq, Read)
```

The Lit constructor gets an element of some type (e.g. an Integer value), Invers gets a sub expression and Add gets two sub expressions.

What I want to achieve now is to implement a function called "simplify". It should simplify any expression based on the following axioms:

```
x `add` idenity = x
idenity `add` x = x
x `add` (invers x) = identity
(invers x) `add` x = identity
```

What I've implemented so far is the following:

```
-- simplify --------------------------------------------------------------------

-- simplify simplifies expression trees applying Group laws as follows ---------
--   add x zero = x
--   add zero x = x
--   add x (minus x) = zero 
--   add (minus x) x = zero 

----- Match for any axiom ----
simplify :: (Group a) =>  Expr a -> Expr a
simplify (Add(Lit x) (Invers (Lit y)))  | x == y  = Lit identity
simplify (Invers (Invers (Lit x))) = Lit x
simplify (Invers (Lit identity)) = Lit identity
simplify (Add(Lit x) (Lit identity)) = Lit x
simplify (Add(Lit identity) (Lit x)) = Lit x

----- No axiom found, so call simplify recusively ---- 
simplify (Invers x) = simplify (x) --  x is a sub    expression
simplify (Add x y) = Add (simplify x) (simplify y) -- x and/or y are sub expressions
```

My problem is that I cannot match for the "identity" element on the left side of the simplify function.

The line

```
simplify (Invers (Lit identity)) = Lit identity
```

would be the same as

```
simplify (Invers (Lit x)) = Lit x
```

since identity is any variable in this scope. Is there any possibility to match against the identity function of the "Group" class?

Thanks much.

Comment: Why not just `simplify (Inverse (Lit x)) | x == identity = identity`, or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: Totally correct, I didn't know that it is possible to use guards here, thanks very much bennofs!

Comment: @bennofs: one of you two should post that comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just simplify (Inverse (Lit x)) | x == identity = identity, or am I misunderstanding your problem? [bennofs]